# Laravel Login Validation Exception

Tags: laravel

I have used laravel auth facade for user authentication. When I try to login using wrong credentials **Validation Exception** is generated displaying **The given data is invalid**.

[image]

**LoginController.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function redirectTo()
    {
        if(auth()->user()->role_id == 3)
            return 'home';
        else if (auth()->user()->role_id==2)
            return 'expert';
        return redirect('/logout')->with('error','You dont have User access');
    }


}
```

I want it to redirect to login page displaying the error "Invalid Credentials". What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

In redirectTo method you must response string.

```php
 public function redirectTo()
    {
        if(auth()->user()->role_id == 3)
            return 'home';
        else if (auth()->user()->role_id==2)
            return 'expert';
        session()->flash('errors', 'Your message')
        return 'logout';
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have edited the question a little bit. Sorry for the incomplete information before, I think the question is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Laravel 7. It's possible to do using function redirectTo() or without it's usage.

```
public function redirectTo()
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    if($user->role_id == 3) {
        return 'home';
    } else if ($user->role_id == 2) {
        return 'expert';
    }
    $this->guard()->logout();
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([$this->username() => __('You dont have User access.')]);
}
```

If you don't want to use that function, you can do it for example in function validateLogin:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    if ($user && $user->role_id == 3) {
        $this->redirectTo = 'home';
    } elseif ($user && $user->role_id == 2) {
        $this->redirectTo = 'expert';
    } elseif ($user) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([$this->username() => __('You dont have User access.')]);
    }

    return $request->validate([
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}
```

or in function attemptLogin:

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $attempt = $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
    if (!$attempt) {
        return false;
    }

    $user = $this->guard()->getLastAttempted();
    if ($user->role_id == 3) {
        $this->redirectTo = 'home';
    } elseif ($user->role_id == 2) {
        $this->redirectTo = 'expert';
    } else {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([$this->username() => __('You dont have User access.')]);
    }
    return true;
}
```